# Calculating 179 Vehicle Deduction with Trade in

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, car

Let's say you trade in a work car that you never depreciated for a new truck that qualifies for the 179 100% deduction (truck has a GVWR over 6,000-pounds).

To keep the numbers simple, the work car gets you 5k on the trade in and the new truck is 30k. Would you be able to take the 179 deduction on the 30k or 25k?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

"Certain vehicles (with a gross vehicle weight rating above 6,000 lbs. but no more than 14,000 lbs.) qualify for deducting up to $25,000 if the vehicle is purchased and placed in service prior to December 31 and meets other conditions."

["In general The cost of any sport utility vehicle for any taxable year which may be taken into account under this section shall not exceed $25,000."](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/179)

So you're able to deduct **up to** $25,000 from the cost of the vehicle, if the cost of the vehicle doesn't exceed $25,000. I would consult a tax professional if only because of the end of the clause "and meets other conditions", which are unclear [from the section 179 website.](https://www.section179.org/section_179_vehicle_deductions/) Also check the "other considerations" section at the bottom.